# NP-hardness of approximation for unconstrained submodular maximization

Tags: np-hardness, optimization, approximation-hardness, submodularity

The problem of unconstrained submodular maximization can be phrased as follows:

> Given a non-negative submodular function $f$ on a domain $D$ find a set $S \subseteq D$ maximizing $f(S)$.

Here a *submodular function* is one satisfying
$$ f(A) + f(B) \geq f(A \cup B) + f(A \cap B) $$
for all $A,B \subseteq D$.

[Buchbinder et al.](http://theory.epfl.ch/moranfe/Publications/FOCS2012.pdf) gave a $1/2$-approximation algorithm for this problem. This is best possible in the value oracle model: [Feige et al.](http://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/data/submod-max-SICOMP.pdf) showed that achieving a $(1/2+\epsilon)$-approximation requires exponentially many value oracle queries, for any $\epsilon > 0$.

What if the function $f$ is given explicitly? [Dobzinsky and Vondrák](http://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/data/querytocc.pdf) gave a class of explicit functions for which no $(1/2+\epsilon)$-approximation can be achieved unless $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{RP}$.

My question is:

> Is there a natural class of explicit submodular functions that is NP-hard to $(1/2+\epsilon)$-approximate for all $\epsilon > 0$?

Compared to Dobzinsky and Vondrák's result, I want a result which holds under the assumption $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{P}$ rather than the stronger $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{RP}$, and moreover I want the class of explicit functions to be *natural*, in contrast to the ingenious but somewhat contrived functions used by Dobzinsky and Vondrák.

For the related problem of monotone submodular maximization subject to a matroid constraint, such a beast does exist: [Feige](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring07/cps296.2/papers/p634-feige.pdf) famously showed that is it NP-hard to approximate Maximum Coverage any better than $1-1/e$, which matches both the value oracle hardness and the best approximation algorithms.

Comment: Is there a natural class for which we have a weaker but still meaningful bound? Say a class for which we cannot get better than $2/3$-approximation?